# How can I check if a MySql field is equal to 1?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a forum in PHP and using MySql as a database, and was wondering how I could check if a MySql field topic_locked was equal to 1. If it isn't, the reply code would be displayed. How can I check this, and if you can help me find how to check this, how could I set it to 1 through the forum?

Comment: Post your code and database table structure.

Comment: We need something to work with. Database structure? Existing code?

Comment: Hey provide some table structure and what you have tried....

Comment: `WHERE topic_locked <> 1` or may be `CASE WHEN topic_locked = 1 THEN ... ELSE something else END`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know your code. But I am sharing simple program to check a mysql field's value.

```
<?php

// Database select and connect to host


$sql= mysql_query("SELECT topic_locked FROM table WHERE Id='your_id'");
$res= mysql_fetch_array($sql);

$value= $res['topic_locked'];

if($value=='1')
{
// reply code
}
?>
```

Update asked,

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['update']))
        {
        $id= $_POST['id'];
        //Database select and connect to host
        mysql_query("UPDATE table SET topic_locked='1' WHERE Id='$id'");
        }
   ?>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="your_id" />
        <input type="submit" name="update" />
        </form>
```

Comment: That has helped me a ton. For the update part, how can I have a button perform that?

Comment: Thanks for updating so quickly! It only shows the if. `$sql= mysql_query("SELECT topic_locked FROM topics");
    $res= mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    $value= $res['topic_locked'];

    if($value=='1')
    {
     echo '<tr><td colspan="2"><p>Sorry; this topic has been locked.</p></td></tr>';
    }
    else 
    {
     echo '<tr><td colspan="2"><h2>Reply:</h2><br />
      <form method="post" action="reply.php?id=' . $row['topic_id'] . '">
       <textarea name="reply-content"></textarea><br /><br />
       <input id="button" type="submit" value="Submit reply" />
      </form></td></tr>';
    }`

Comment: What should I put for the where condition?

Comment: @user1640021: You should really mark this answer as accepted. The responder gave a good answer to a multipart question that was ask rather poorly.